# Raw Meta Tags in Open Graph properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook-opengraph

I created simple html page with meta tags to share some image,texts and url on facebook.I hosted this file and saw that link in Open Graph Object Debugger.but it only get images and descriptions of raw tags in my og:url property.it didnt show og:image,og:description property in my page.I want to add url,different image and description.how add meta tag to do that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta property="og:url"  content="http://www.google.com" />
<meta property="og:description" content="some text" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/images/image1.jpg" />
<meta property="og:title"  content="title" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>    
</body>
</html>
```